# Katalog for Envi

Tags: image, envi, catalog-service

I am working In Process of Image Cataloging of Satellite Imagery. For That I have found Free extension software in ENVI  called "KATALOG" but I cannot find any useful resources for Downloading it.

Are there any useful resources for downloading it?

Comment: For reference, a description of KATALOG (from the [Exelis Blog](https://www.exelisvis.com/Company/PressRoom/Blogs/TabId/836/ArtMID/2928/ArticleID/5334/5334.aspx)): _“Katalog” is a free satellite image cataloguing tool [...] [which] can crawl a particular folder structure in search of the satellite images, extracting both metadata, footprints, and thumbnails. This information is then searchable by a number of variables (e.g. name, sensor, geographic location, date, description, and so on) allowing users to quickly find scenes in their imagery libraries, discovering and rediscovering data [...]_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [powerpoint announcement of ENVI 5.0](http://www.exelisvis.com/portals/0/pdfs/Adam_OConnor_ENVI_5%200.pdf#page=13), **[Katalog](https://www.exelisvis.com/Company/PressRoom/Blogs/TabId/836/PID/2928/TagID/90/TagName/katalog/Default.aspx)** should be available via the [*Exelis Code library*](http://www.exelisvis.com/Learn/CodeLibrary.aspx).

Unfortunately, the code library is **offline** at the time of writing due to some [legal issues](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.idl-pvwave/D1yqgA5IVFs/y4mPJTor2aoJ). Other authors have already moved their stuff to github (e.g. the [ENVI Plugins](https://github.com/dawhite/ENVIPlugins) by [Devin White](http://web.ornl.gov/sci/gist/staff_bios/staff_whited.shtml)). I could not find the KATALOG software either, but I suppose you contact its authors, *Eduardo
Iturrate et al.*, and ask them. The KATALOG software was presented on [poster *IN23C-1513* at AGU fall meeting 2012](http://fallmeeting.agu.org/2012/files/2012/11/AGUPoster2-12_EI.pdf). You find an author's e-mail address on it - give it a try. Maybe he can point you to a useful resource or even provide you the package directly.